# Login prompt for opening a office document from SharePoint library in IE.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, internet-explorer

There are few excel files in my SharePoint 2010 library which is a public facing site. Now when I click on the files from Chrome browser, the files get downloaded in my machine but when I try from IE(IE 11) there is a prompt to OPEN, SAVE and SAVE AS. Of which, if I click on OPEN I get a login prompt.

I tried adding the site in TRUSTED Site zone but still the issue occurs. If I click on cancel of login prompt the file opens without any issue. Question is why I am getting this login prompt in IE and not in another browser.

Is it some IE issues?

Please share if any has info on this behavior. Thanks.

Comment: See maybe here: http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-to-disable-the-password-prompt-in-sharepoint-2013 or here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/db8cedb3-9db7-4844-9b91-1675e60c9b85/sharepoint-prompts-user-to-login?forum=sharepointadmin or here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c20cd7a5-83bb-4398-80a7-dd08d8bff571/sharepoint-2010-constant-prompt-for-credentials-to-edit-office-documents-in-a-fqdn-setup?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious. Could be Loopback Check or FQDN in Trusted Sites in my opinion.

Comment: In your IE goto Settings->Security->Custom Level->User Authentication and check the value selected. It should not be prompt user and password and if it is Automatic logon on only intranet zone. Then check if your web app is added to Intranet Zone or not.

Comment: DID everything..NO SUCCESS..Any other alternative anyone!!

Comment: When I have trouble with MS documents not opening in IE, I repair Office and it usually fixes my issue

Comment: its not about problem in opening..its all about login prompt.check the question